# Django: View is not putting the value returned by a function

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have the `bookingrecordsView` view in which I fetch all reservations made by a user. I added a model function `is_pending()` that fetches a reservation instance, checks whether the `date_to` field has passed or not, and returns a string.
The view that fetches the reservations:

```
def bookingrecordsView(request):
    rsv = Reservation.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'booking_history_page.html', {'rsv': rsv})
```

And the function that checks the date:

```
class Reservation (models.Model):
    ....
    ​@property
    Def is_pending(self):
        if self.date_to < datetime.date.today():
            return "Pending"
        else:
            return "Over"
```

This is my template snippet:

```
{% for r in rsv %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ r.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.date_from }} - {{ r.date_to }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.time_from }} - {{ r.time_to }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.chosen_vehicle }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.garage }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.destination }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.is_pending }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, for all the bookings, even those passed months earlier, this `status` is always returning 'Pending'.

How do I get the correct return value for every `Reservation` instance from `is_pending()` function and pass it accordingly to the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated?

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def is_pending(self):
        return self.date_to < datetime.date.today()
```

Get rid of that function and refer this property as a regular field in your template. Like this:

```
{{ r.is_pending }}
```

You can alter this function to make it returning status description or implement it (convertion to 'pending', 'over') in the template.

Comment: I am using this solution but stumbled on how do i call this in my view?

Comment: Property method can treated as an attribute of the object. Hence, you can simply access `is_pending` from a Reservation instance, for example like this:`for r in rsv: print(r.is_pending)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not considering each reservation properly, you want to instead do something more like this:

```
def bookingrecordsView(request):
    rsv = Reservation.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    condition = checkIfPending(rsv)
    return render(request, 'booking_history_page.html', {'rsv': rsv})
```

`checkIfPending` function

```
def checkIfPending(rsv):
    for r in rsv:
        if r.date_to < datetime.date.today():
            r.status = "Pending"
        else:
            r.status = "Over"
```

And the template

```
{% for r in rsv %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ r.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.date_from }} - {{ r.date_to }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.time_from }} - {{ r.time_to }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.chosen_vehicle }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.garage }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.destination }}</td>
    <td>{{ r.status }}</td>       <-- Placed 'status' here
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, you can also define a `status` method in your `Reservation` model that you can directly access with `r.status` or similar. This will avoid having to loop over all the reservations just to set this value.